# How to set timer between two button clicks

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, media-player, alassetslibrary

I have one button on the screen to start a camera and one button to stop the camera.  Basically it's for video recording. So I am just trying to set a timer to determine the total duration of these video files.

```
//start camera

- (IBAction)startCamera:(id)sender {

if (!recording)
{
//----- START RECORDING -----
NSLog(@"START RECORDING");
recording = YES;


//Create temporary URL to record to
NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"output.mov"];
NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputPath];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:outputPath])
{
}
//Start recording
[MovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];     


//stop camera

-(void)stopCamera:(id)sender {

//----- STOP RECORDING -----

NSLog(@"STOP RECORDING");
recording = NO;
[MovieFileOutput stopRecording];


//i have used this for get the time but keep saying 00.00.00
//Create temporary URL to record to
NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"output.mov"];
NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputPath];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:outputURL options:nil];
CMTime videoDuration = videoAsset.duration;
float videoDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(videoDuration);

NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:videoDurationSeconds];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];  //we can vary the date string. Ex: "mm:ss"
NSString* result = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Duration 2 of this after stopping : %2@",result);
}
}
```

Comment: I need to get total duration of a video.. I am using AVAsset for it. but keep getting zero seconds :/

Comment: Improved language and puncuation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a custom counter method. YOu can try this code.

Create timer and counter properties

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSTimer *startTimer;
@property (assign) NSInteger x;
```

and give the x 0 in `viewDidAppear`.

and start the timer when you start recording:

```
 -(IBAction)start:(id)sender{
    [self startReading];

    _startTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(count)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];

}

-(IBAction)stop:(id)sender{
    [self stopReading];

    [_startTimer invalidate];

}

-(void)count{

    NSLog(@"video duration %ld",(long)_x);
    _x=_x+1;
double seconds = fmod(_x, 60.0);
double minutes = fmod(trunc(_x / 60.0), 60.0);
double hours = trunc(_x / 3600.0);
self.timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02.0f:%02.0f:%04.1f", hours, minutes, seconds];

}
```

and you can get the time from _x. Reset the time and again do your stuff.

Comment: Thank you but I should have at least two decimal to show time.. @Mr.T

Comment: do you mean you need time in format 00,01,02,03 seconds ?

Comment: i would like to see seconds and minutes together. like 00.05.. @Mr.T

Comment: Thank you so much. @Mr.T